# SQL Like Statement with multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-like

I am having an issue getting this to work. I have multiple WHERE statements that need to happen based on conditional information from the search query. Within there I can't seem to get the `LIKE` statements to work.

In the database the `STREET_NUM` & `STREET_NAME` are in different rows. I am using one input field to check against called `$address`

I am also struggling with getting the `MIN` & `MAX` to work.

Here is the Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM arc_property_res WHERE ( arc_property_res.STATUS = 'Active'";
        if(!empty($_GET['city'])){
            // City only query!
            $sql .= "AND arc_property_res.CITY = '{$_GET['city']}'";
        }
        if(!empty($_GET['neighborhood'])){
            // Hood only query!
            $sql .= "AND arc_property_res.SUBDIVISION = '{$_GET['neighborhood']}'";
        }
        if(!empty($_GET['mls-number'])){
            // MLS only query!
            $sql .= "AND arc_property_res.MLS_ACCT = '{$_GET['mls-number']}'";
        }
        if(!empty($_GET['min-price']) && !empty($_GET['max-price'])){
            // MIN AND MAX only query!
            $sql .= "AND arc_property_res.LIST_PRICE = MIN('{$_GET['min-price']}') MAX('{$_GET['max-price']}')";
        }
        if(!empty($_GET['num-of-beds'])){
            // BEDS only query!
            $sql  .= "AND arc_property_res.BEDROOMS = '{$_GET['num-of-beds']}'";
        }
        if(!empty($_GET['num-of-baths'])){
            // BATHS only query!
            $sql  .= "AND arc_property_res.BATHS_FULL = '{$_GET['num-of-baths']}'";
        }
        if(!empty($_GET['mls-number'])){
            // BATHS only query!
            $sql  .= "AND arc_property_res.MLS_ACCT = '{$_GET['mls-number']}'";
        }
        if(!empty($_GET['address'])){
            $sql  .= "AND arc_property_res.STREET_NUM LIKE '%{$_GET['address']}'";
            $sql  .= "OR arc_property_res.STREET_NAME LIKE '{$_GET['address']}%'";
        }

    $sql .= ") ORDER BY {$orderby}{$price_order}{$comma}{$list_date}";
```

Comment: Could you post your result query, just to read it easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need are some parentheses around the `arc_property_res.STREET_NUM`. Further, I would recommend you add some spaces around each line in your entire code so that you don't get syntax errors.

```
if(!empty($_GET['address'])){
    $sql  .= " AND (arc_property_res.STREET_NUM LIKE '%{$_GET['address']}' ";
    $sql  .= " OR arc_property_res.STREET_NAME LIKE '{$_GET['address']}%') ";
}
```

Comment: Hm, tried but nothing. It only works if I put just an Address NUM or just the Street Name in. but it won't look for both using the OR statement.

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect what you have provided. It just still treats them as separate items and doesn't look for both at the same time.

Comment: `LIKE` may not give you the functionality that you are expecting. You may need to look into fuzzy matching or split up the address completely.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the obvious ["Bobby Tables" issue that your query has](http://xkcd.com/327/), the problem at hand is that you do not insert a space in front of `AND`. This results in queries that look like this:

```
AND arc_property_res.BEDROOMS =3AND arc_property_res.BATHS_FULL =2
```

Note that there is no space between `3` and `AND` - a syntax error.

You should look into parametrizing your queries, and modifying it in a way that ignores the parameters that have been set to `NULL`.

```
SELECT * FROM arc_property_res WHERE ( arc_property_res.STATUS = 'Active'
AND (arc_property_res.CITY = @cityParam OR @cityParam is NULL)
AND (arc_property_res.SUBDIVISION = @subdiv OR @subdiv is NULL)
...
)
```

This modification would let you keep the query the same regardless of the number of parameters that were actually set, get you the same results, taking pretty much the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`$sql .= "AND arc_property_res.LIST_PRICE = MIN('{$_GET['min-price']}') MAX('{$_GET['max-price']}')";`

The min and max functions are for when you want to get the min and max of a field in your database.

What you want is to compare the list price to see if it falls in between the min and max values supplied by the user.

```
 $sql .= " AND arc_property_res.LIST_PRICE >= '{$_GET['min-price']}' AND arc_property_res.LIST_PRICE <= '{$_GET['max-price']}'";
```